# How can a write and draw the "concave" version of a log regression using lm() and ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm

I need to modify a log regression when I changes my y-axis data from y to 100-y (y is a percentage), but I don't find how to do it.
I use the following toy example:

```
m=c(3,1,3,2,4,7,10,2,1,44,11,24,1,3,5,11,7,17,8,10,17,34,31,10,7,3,1,6,4,3,4,7,11,14,6,8,34,80,23,54,2,3,2,1,13,8,10,15,2,15,8,11,8,12,9,18,85)
q=c(91,78,72,84,74,76,81,80,70,130,131,136,53,56,57,111,60,80,78,76,84,107,85,76,57,57,45,50,68,61,52,59,60,60,51,63,95,93,85,97,52,39,34,40,70,124,90,68,39,81,50,60,74,70,59,53,98)
Age=c(rep("Young",24),rep("Old",33))
df=data.frame(Age,m,q)
```

Considering the scatter plot (below), I tried both a linear and log regression:

```
model_lin_df <- df %>% group_by(Age) %>% do(model = glance(lm(m ~ q,data = .))) %>% unnest(model)
> model_lin_df
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  Age   r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic  p.value    df logLik   AIC   BIC deviance df.residual  nobs
  <chr>     <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>       <int> <int>
1 Old       0.370         0.350 16.4       18.2 0.000172     1 -138.   282.  287.    8339.          31    33
2 Young     0.418         0.391  8.97      15.8 0.000646     1  -85.7  177.  181.    1771.          22    24

model_exp_df <- df %>% group_by(Age) %>% do(model = glance(lm(log(m) ~ q,data = .))) %>% unnest(model)
model_exp_df
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  Age   r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic    p.value    df logLik   AIC   BIC deviance df.residual  nobs
  <chr>     <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>       <int> <int>
1 Old       0.517         0.502 0.776      33.2 0.00000242     1  -37.4  80.8  85.3     18.7          31    33
2 Young     0.362         0.333 0.916      12.5 0.00187        1  -30.9  67.8  71.4     18.5          22    24
```

And draw the respective lines:

```
model_lin <- lm(m ~ Age/q + 0, df,na.action=na.exclude)
model_exp <- lm(log(m) ~ Age/q + 0, df,na.action=na.exclude)

df_plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = q, y = m, shape=Age, color=Age)) + geom_point() +
                geom_line(aes(y = ifelse(Age == "Young", fitted(model_lin), NA))) +
                geom_line(aes(y = ifelse(Age == "Old", exp(fitted(model_exp)), NA))) +
                theme_bw() + theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

But in fact, I should plot the y-axis as 100-y, because it would be more meaningful for the data. I fail to plot the "inverse" version of the log regression:

```
s=100-m
df=cbind(df,s)
```

Writing the models already shows that I should modify my formula:

```
> model_lin_df2 <- df %>% group_by(Age) %>% do(model = glance(lm(s ~ q,data = .))) %>% unnest(model)
> model_lin_df2
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  Age   r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic  p.value    df logLik   AIC   BIC deviance df.residual  nobs
  <chr>     <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>       <int> <int>
1 Old       0.370         0.350 16.4       18.2 0.000172     1 -138.   282.  287.    8339.          31    33
2 Young     0.418         0.391  8.97      15.8 0.000646     1  -85.7  177.  181.    1771.          22    24

> model_exp_df2 <- df %>% group_by(Age) %>% do(model = glance(lm(log(s) ~ q,data = .))) %>% unnest(model)
> model_exp_df2
    # A tibble: 2 x 13
      Age   r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic  p.value    df logLik   AIC   BIC deviance df.residual  nobs
      <chr>     <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>       <int> <int>
    1 Old       0.286         0.263 0.363      12.4 0.00134      1  -12.3  30.7  35.2    4.08           31    33
    2 Young     0.408         0.381 0.115      15.1 0.000788     1   18.9 -31.8 -28.3    0.291          22    24
```

The stats are the same for the linear model (as expected, it is just a negative curve), not for the log one. I tried an exponential, `lm(exp(s) ~ q`, I thought a "-exp()" would make it but it doesn't (the r²-squared do not match those of the log(m) ~ q model). I also tried with 1/log and other options, but I don't find the appropriate way of writing and drawing the curve for the "Old" category. This is the plot with the log:

```
model_lin2 <- lm(s ~ Age/q + 0, df,na.action=na.exclude)
model_exp2 <- lm(log(s) ~ Age/q + 0, df,na.action=na.exclude)

df_plot2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = q, y = s, shape=Age, color=Age)) + geom_point() +
              geom_line(aes(y = ifelse(Age == "Young", fitted(model_lin2), NA))) +
              geom_line(aes(y = ifelse(Age == "Old", exp(fitted(model_exp2)), NA))) +
              theme_bw() + theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

Any idea about how to do this would be appreciated. I believe that as for the linear regression, the stats (r², p-value) should be the same on the 100-y plot as on the first plot.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, possibly it can be reframed for stats.stackexchange.com, but briefly the models aren't the same. You might want to consider a glm with a log link function, but fundamentally log(100-m)~ax is a different model to log(m)~ax

Comment: I feel it is a mix quastion, math/code, and that part of the question is valid for here. I will need to write the formula properly to be able to add it to the plot. In the meanwhile, I will consider a glm (thanks), post the math question to statexchange if I cannot figure it out by myself, and post an update when I have the formula.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the plot that you want would be to transform the estimates from your first model. This avoids trying to find an equivalent model for s directly (there is no linear model for log(s) equivalent to your model for log(m)). The code would be:

```
df_plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = q, y = s, shape=Age, color=Age)) + geom_point() +
                geom_line(aes(y = ifelse(Age == "Young", 100 - fitted(model_lin), NA))) +
                geom_line(aes(y = ifelse(Age == "Old", 100 - exp(fitted(model_exp)), NA))) +
                theme_bw() + theme(panel.grid = element_blank())

df_plot
```

[image: Output plot]

Note that to be able to better compare the linear and log models it might be better to have the same response variable, so change `lm(log(m)~x+0)` to `glm(m~x+0, family=gaussian(link="log))`

Comment: Thanks @Miff. I don't use glm much, I am going through SO and other sites to figure out how to properly interpret & plot the results. And how to obtain separated results for each Age. Also, I had to use "link" instead of "type" : `glm(m ~ Age/q + 0,family=gaussian(link="log"), df,na.action=na.exclude)`. Agreed, log(100-m)~ax is a different model to log(m)~ax, but I don't get why I cannot make a simple exponential lm model. Considering the shape of f(x)=-exp(x), I would expect a decent result with lm(). It would just provide an easy r² and p-value. Maybe coding just exp(s) ~ q is not enough?

Comment: Good catch about the argument (now corrected). At the moment I don't think that there's anything else I can add about the choice of model

Comment: Ok thank you @Miff for your help!